# Custom focus on Asp.net elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am new user at stackoverflow. I am facing issue to set custom focus on certain elements on asp.net. We can use asp.net or java script functionality.

[My current page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYgM6.png)

I want to focus on first with page load on payment 1 text box then payment mode 1 dropdown and then save button.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `TabIndex` from control property in asp.net or you can use jquery to set focus by `$("element").focus()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do all that using HTML and JavaScript:

First assign an id attribute to the payment_1 element. For example (ad "id" to input html element):

```
<input id="payment1">
```

Then using JavaScript focus that input field:

```
document.getElementById('payment1').focus();
```

If you want your users to have the ability to move between input fields with a "Tab" button in a different order than the default (left to right, up to down), then assign tabindex attribute to elements. For example:

```
<input id="payment1" tabindex="1">
<button id="save" tabindex="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any JS for this. Just use autofocus

```
<input type="text" name="payment1" tabindex="1" autofocus />
```

So now on page load that field should be focussed. then tabindex the other fields in the order you want them to focus.